# How to add Scroll in ipad application

Tags: jquery, ipad, iscroll4

I am using IScroll4 in my application to add scroll in that particular div for ipad  but I am not able to add scroll 
  I used

```
function loaded(){

    scroll = new iScroll('wrapper');
      }
     document.addEventListener('load', loaded, false);
```

the above is my div structure

Answer (score 0):

The function that you have defined is not your `div` structure. It is to initialize `iscroll` for the defined div with id `wrapper`. You may show your `html` for the div structure. Moreover, you have to define `var scroll;` before writing `scroll = ...;`. Also if you have only text and all images have fixed dimensions (ie: explicit width/height) you may use the `DOMContentLoaded` event. In general `iscroll4` has no working issue in ipad. May be you have you have missed something. Check the documention from http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4 and still if you find problem then specify exaclty what you are trying to do and where you are stuck. Your question does not explain much.